# Get all Max value in all sheets in Column A located in a dynamic range

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a code to do the specific task:

1. Go through each sheet and get the MAX of the last 365 rows in *Column E*.
2. The range is dynamic because each sheet have different number of rows. So I decided to use this codes:

   ```
   Sheets(Cells(i, 1).Value).Range("E1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(-365, 0).Address
   Sheets(Cells(i, 1).Value).Range("E1048576").End(xlUp).Address
   ```

   so it will return the *(a)* Last row minus 365 rows *(b)* Last Row resulting to Range(a to b)
3. I added the `WorksheetFunction.Max` function to get the max number.
4. My code is inside a for loop which gets the sheet names in *Column A*.

   ```
   Private Sub tester()

       Dim i As Integer

       LastRow = Sheets("Stocks Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

       For i = 2 To LastRow

       Cells(i, 13).Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(Sheets(Cells(i, 1).Value). _
           Range("E1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(-365, 0).Address & ":" & _
           Sheets(Cells(i, 1).Value).Range("E1048576").End(xlUp).Address))

       Next i

   End Sub
   ```

**My error:**

Everytime I run the macro, it returns 0. I don't understand why and what went wrong.
If somebody could help me with the code, I will truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub tester()

    Dim i As Long, LastRow as Long, c As Range
    Dim shtSumm As Worksheet, rng as Range

    Set shtSumm = Sheets("Stocks Summary")

    LastRow = shtSumm.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each c in shtSumm.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Cells

        Set rng = Sheets(c.Value).Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp). _
                      Offset(-364, 0).Resize(365, 1)

        c.EntireRow.Cells(13).Value = Application.Max(rng)

    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: There's something wrong with the code in line "Set rng = Sheets(c.Value).Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Offset(-364, 0).Resize(365, 1)"

Comment: What's wrong?   It will error if there are fewer than 365 rows (see @L42's answer for that fix), but otherwise it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The only obvious problem is referencing. To learn more about it, [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).
 Not really about avoiding the use of `Select` but on how to reference objects.
 Anyhow, you can make your code simpler by working directly on all the sheets.
 Something like below:

```
Sub contract()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, oWS As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range
    Dim olr As Long, lr As Long, i As Long

    '/* this is where you get sheet list and output max */
    Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stocks Summary")
    olr = oWS.Range("A" & oWS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To olr
        '/* set the worksheet */
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(oWS.Cells(i, 1).Value2)
        With ws
            lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            '/* added an if to make sure, you have 365 rows
            'else it will error out */
            If lr >= 365 Then
                '/* you only offset by -364 rows,
                'then use resize to select up to 365 rows below it */
                Set r = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-364).Resize(365)
            Else
                '/* set the range up to the max last row only */
                Set r = .Range("A2:A" & lr)
            End If
        End With
        '/* output the max, or the min for that matter */
        oWS.Cells(i, 13).Value2 = Application.Max(r)
    Next
End Sub
```